# Converting data in SSIS from flat file

Tags: ssis, format

I'm trying to import an important number of columns (around 100) from a flat file to a database using SSIS 2008.

My issue is that the data read is in bad format (for dates (format "yyyyMMdd") and doubles(format "XXXXX.XX" with a point instead of a comma)). Of course I can code all the transformations using a script component (to convert string columns to wanted type) but it takes too much time and patience.

Did you guys encounter this type of issues ? Is there a quicker way to do what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [locale of the flat file connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140266.aspx) to US English? Alternatively, just load the data into `varchar` columns with no transformation and then convert the data in the database, that might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Flat File Connection Manager Editor and change the data types of each column as desired.

```
Right Click on your Flat File Connection >> Click on 'Advanced' option 
and then set the datatype of each Column as required.
```

Comment: for dates ,once u have loaded them in the db , you can use CONVERT() function to convert it into the desired format.